# One of the current project(s)

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

I need a title that will introduce only one of several projects I'm currently working on :

Will it be correct to write this title :

> One of the current projectS:

Note: the title needs to show that I'm working on several projects even if only one will be listed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. To indicate that they are your projects, you could also say *one of my current projects*.

"One of the current project" would make little sense, because you would indicate that there only *is* one current project.

Consider the following:

> I take one of the apples from the basket.

It means that there are *several* apples in the basket, and I take one of *them*. I cannot be taking *one* of the *one apple*.

When you use this in a sentence, make sure that the *whole phrase* is a *singular*:

> There *are* some apples in the basket.
>   One of the apples *is* rotten.